# ¿Cómo se llama este efecto y cómo se hace?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, webgl

¿Cómo puedo crear un **background** tipo `broken-glass` como el de la siguiente página? Sé que se desarrolla con ***three.js*** y con ***webGl***, pero ¿Cuál es el nombre? ¿Existe algún tutorial?

http://www.kawanoshinjuku.com